# Does using FreeDOS allow my program to access more than 64 K of memory?

Tags: c, assembly, dos, x86-16, memory-limit

I am interested in programming in C on FreeDOS while learning some basic ASM in the process, will using FreeDOS allow my program to access more than the standard 640K of memory?

And secondly, about the ASM, I know on modern processors it is hard to program on assembly due to the complexity of the CPU architecture, but does using FreeDOS limit me to the presumably simpler 16-bit instruction set?

Comment: Do you mean 640k? And look up [DOS extender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_extender).

Comment: I would consider using dosbox to run your code.

Comment: 1) Yes, you get it in 64kb 'segments' - there are 10 that are (easily)available. 2) Both MS/DR DOS allowed you to use 32 bit instructions - freedos reports problems with 386 mode wfw 3.11 - At a guess, due to incomplete support for entering/leaving protected mode.

Comment: I remember loading up FreeDOS on my desktop with XMS and it reported ~4 GB of RAM, is that all accessible(declare variables, use pointers, etc...) like normally, or is there some considerations I need to take into account?

Comment: I can't imagine *why* you find the 16 bits mode of recent x86 processors *simpler* than their 32 bits or 64 bits mode.... ; that 16 bits mode is mostly a legacy thing.

Comment: Your question follows a common pattern of stating "I know..." followed by something contrary to fact. If you don't know, say you don't know and then ask, rather than making wrong assumptions.

Comment: R & Basile, scratch what I've said. Is it reasonably simple to program in assembly on modern processors 32 bit/64 bit modes? I'm just now wanting to get into lower level programming, please be forgiving of my mistakes and false assumptions.

Comment: Heh! Define "reasonably". It is within your power to program in 16-bit and/or 32-bit and/or 64-bit mode, if you want to. Modern CPUs still know all the "simple" instructions. You don't need to use the "exotic" stuff. FreeDOS won't prevent you from using 4G of memory, or using 32-bit or even 64-bit instructions. You may have to jump through some hoops. FreeDOS won't give you too much help, but it won't prevent you from doing whatever you want (within the capabilities of your hardware). A protected mode OS is protected from US! With FreeDOS, you own the whole machine.

Comment: Writing a user space asm on 32Bit protected mode is definitely easier and convenient, then writing code for 16Bit DOS with all it's segemnt stuff and limitations.

Comment: 16 bit is dead. Even BIOS is 32 bit (early boot) and a little later runs in 64 bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any extender a program can use maximum 640KB of low memory in DOS. But each structure will be limited to the size of a segment, or 64KB. That means you can have 10 large arrays of size 64KB. Of course you can have multiple arrays in a segment but their total size must not exceed the segment size. Some compilers also handle addresses spanning across multiple segments automatically so you can use objects larger than 64KB seamlessly, or you can also do the same if you're writing in assembly

To access more memory you need an extender like [EMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanded_memory#EMS) or [XMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_memory). But note that the address space is still 20-bit wide. The extenders just map the high memory regions into some segments in the addressable space so you can only see a small window of your data at a time

Regarding assembly, you can use 32-bit registers in 16-bit mode. There are 66h and 67h prefixes to change the operand size. However that doesn't mean that writing 16-bit code is easier. In fact it has lots of idiosyncrasies to remember like the limited register usage in memory addressing. The 32-bit x86 instruction set is a lot cleaner with saner addressing modes as well as a flat address space which is a lot easier to use.

Comment: Untrue.  Huge memory model in C permits segmented space to be treated as flat space by including the segment in all pointers.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: no, including the segment in pointer just makes it acts like a far pointer. That doesn't mean that the pointer can be freely used as a flat pointer. For example you cannot do direct arithmetic operations such as `ptr + 200` like flat pointer. Of course the compiler or programmer can handle this, but this's a different problem

Comment: In the huge model, the compiler *does* do all that work for you, so you *can* just increment pointers and use arrays of greater than 64 KiB.  That's the whole point.  You're describing the large memory model, which does not do that.

Answer (score 4):

MS-DOS and FreeDOS use the "HIMEM" areas: These are:

- Some memory areas above 0xA000:0x0000 reserved for extension cards that contain RAM instead of extension cards
- The memory starting from 0xFFFF:0x0010 to 0xFFFF:0xFFFF which is located above 1MB but can be accessed using 16-bit real mode code (if the so-called A20-line is active).

The maximum memory size that can be archieved this way is about 800K.

Using XMS and EMS you can use up to 64M:

- XMS will allocate memory blocks above the area that can be accessed via 16-bit real mode code. There are special functions that can copy data from that memory to the low 640K of memory and vice versa
- EMS is similar; however using EMS it is possible to "map" the high memory to a low address (a feature of 32-bit CPUs) which means that you can access some memory above the 1MB area as if it was located at an address below 1MB.

Comment: EMS existed before 32-bit processors, so its mapping feature has actually nothing to do with paging features present in 386+ processors. 386 processors allowed back in the day EMS to be emulated, by switching the processor into V8086 mode and managing memory from protected mode, with paging enabled.

Comment: ... which means that using older processors additional hardware was necessary and using 386+ EMS is a pure software feature.